# Gradle Copy format to include several files

Tags: gradle

I would like to use the Gradle `Copy` task, and to specify several files to include from the given directory.

I have seen the syntax with several `include` directives:

```
task myTask (type: Copy) {
   from: myDir {
      include "file1.txt"
      include "file2.csv"
      include "file3.xml"
   }
   into: dest
}
```

But I would like to do that in one line, so that I can use a variable I receive as argument of the `include` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is simply to pass an array of Strings:

```
task myTask (type: Copy) {
   from: myDir {
      include ["file1.txt", "file2.csv", "file3.xml", "**/otherfile", "*.java"]
   }
   into: dest
}
```